# Page rendering more narrow and not centered on iPad

Tags: ipad, centering

Here is a [page](http://mat.miracosta.edu/MAT235/studentwork/Ng_Gary/typography/Ng_typography.html) I am working on for a class.  Don't worry that it's all divs - the exercise allows that as it was to experiment with web fonts.

My problem is that the page renders fine in IE, Firefox, Safari, but on the iPad it doesn't center and the scale is off.  If you look at the top left header "Top of the Napkin", it actually breaks into 2 lines on the iPad.  There is no left margin yet quite a bit of right margin.

thanks for any help -

Answer (score 3):

The above answer did not work for me on the iPad. Here is what did work.
In the body tag I added the minimum width of what I would want in a browser.

```
body { min-width:1080px; }
```

This worked without adding

```
<meta name="viewport" width=device-width />
```

but I left it in the header for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the page on my iPad (latest IOS v5.1) and I can see the text "Top of the Napkin" on one line, though you are right about the entire page not getting center aligned..

For that, I would suggest you to do 2 things;

**A.** Set the viewport width as below (add this line inside your head element);

```
<meta name="viewport" width=device-width />
```

The above line would set your viewport width to device-width (i.e. 768px on the iPad). You can even hard code the value as

```
<meta name="viewport" width=900 />
```

Though this is not the best approach.

**B.** The other thing you can try is giving the following style to your body element

```
margin:0 auto
```

This would effectively center align your entire page.

There is some real good information on how to design websites for mobile (iPhone/iPad, etc) on http://bit.ly/rs1npZ

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a viewport meta tag. Check the link for info on what this does and which to choose. http://www.allenpike.com/2010/choosing-a-viewport-for-ipad-sites/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

for my part, the page was broken because of div elements bigger than their container.

i fixed it by playing with overflow-x property.

You may try putting overflow-x:hidden; on your containers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is how I fixed it:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=.9" />
```